# Need help with the seams on this leather couch I'm working on

Tags: texturing, uv, uv-image-editor

So I'm following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcWM9PBCVHw&t=474s) tutorial and I'm having major difficulties with the seams.  I was able to get them working on the back and side cushions, but the seat cushions are not cooperating with me.  I'm using 1 UV map for the leather and a separate one for the seams, but for some reason the seams texture is facing the wrong way on 2 of the edges.  I've attached some screenshots of the issue.  Any help would be greatly appreciated[image]

Answer (score 0):

Alright so I figured out a janky fix, but I'm not sure if it's the best way or not.  I selected just the faces with the sideways seams and manually rotated them all in the UV image editor, then manually placed them in the center of the image and scaled up till they matched the others.